# Need to extract an integer from a filename string

Tags: java, regex

I have several png image files with names like this -

- house_number_5.png
- house_number_512.png
- house_number_52352.png

I need to extract the integers from these filenames...5, 12, 2352 in the case above. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What regex have you tried so far?

Comment: You don't even need a regexp for that.  You can just split on . and _.

Comment: @Corbin So I have to perform two split operations? Would regexp be better as it could get the integer in one operation?

Comment: One operation does not always mean more efficient.  My guess is that two splits would actually be faster.

Comment: oops, I have fixed the question, my filenames actually have two _'s in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just copy and paste. it is a really working version. (and sorry for the previous version which doesn't work)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("house_(\\d+)\\.png");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("house_234.png");

        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1)); //print the number
        }
    }
}
```

result

```
234
```

Comment: `%d`? You mean `\d`? This isn't `printf` format. ;-) Just using the pattern `\d+` would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without regex:

```
/* assume valid input */

public int getNumber(String filePath)
{
    int startPos = filePath.lastIndexOf("_");
    int dotPos = filePath.indexOf(".", lastUnderscorePos);
    String numberString = filePath.substring(startPos + 1, dotPos);
    return Integer.parseInt(numberString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern intsOnly = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher makeMatch = intsOnly.matcher("house_number_5.png");
makeMatch.find();
String inputInt = makeMatch.group();
System.out.println(inputInt);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the filename
2. Remove the .png using substring(..) method.
3. Use Stringtokenizer , use split(..) method using underscore '_' as the split type.
4. The third token from StringTokenizer will be the number,convert it to integer using parseInt.

Answer (score 0):

Replace-all works with regular expressions:

```
 "house_number_52352.png".replaceAll (".*[^0-9]([0-9]+)\\.png", "$1")
```

- .*[^0-9] take a long chain of characters, which end in a non digit ...
- followed by at least one digit
- and a literal dot
- and a literal png

Replace the whole thing by the group of (at least one digit).